# Android onCreateView not being called

Tags: android

On my developer console I'm getting some errors. One thing about this errors is that they are all from devices with android `4.1` version.

EDIT: Some errors on  4.2 devices but still can't reproduce the exact behavior.

I've set up a emulator device with android version `4.1` and with debbuging I've found that `onCreateView` it's not being called.

I'm using fragments. I have a class to handle the fragments (`public class Fragments extends ActionBarActivity implements QueryFragment.OnQuerySelectedListener`) and after it checks if we are on a two pane or single pane layout the class does this:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(Bundle itemSelectedData) {

    View rightLayout = findViewById(R.id.fragment_two);

    if (rightLayout != null) {
        // do something if we are in "tablet" mode
    } else {
        Infodata newFragment = new Infodata();
        newFragment.setArguments(itemSelectedData);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentsboth, newFragment);
        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

and my class `Infodata`

```
public class Infodata extends Fragment implements OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnItemSelectedListener
```

This class as this methods:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

//... more stuff
    activityContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    bDFav = new Database(activityContext, true);
//... more stuff
}
```

and

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);

    if (isItemFavorite()) {
        //... do something
    } else {
       //... do something else
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
boolean isItemFavorite() {
    bDFav.open();
    // do stuff
    bDFav.close();

    return isFavorite;
}
```

With my phone (android version 4.2.1) my `Fragments` class does `Infodata newFragment = new Infodata();` and after the `transaction.commit();` my `onCreateView` is called instantiating everything that is needed to the `isItemFavorite()` call on `onCreateOptionsMenu`. This makes `bDFav.open();` at `isItemFavorite()` and it work as expected, that is, it does not produce `nullpointerexception`.

On the other and, with the emulator device running android 4.1.1, it runs the same at `transaction.commit();` but after that, my method `onCreateView` it's not called and thus not instantiating anything. `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called ad there when `isItemFavorite()` is called, it produces `nullpointerexception` at `bDFav.open();`.

**Why isn't `onCreateView` being called at that android version and how can I bypass this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.

I've believe I've found the answer.

In the method:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
//... more stuff
    activityContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    bDFav = new Database(activityContext, true);
//... more stuff
}
```

Right after the `onCreateView` I had `setHasOptionMenu(true)` so the method was

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
//... more stuff
    activityContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    bDFav = new Database(activityContext, true);
//... more stuff
}
```

So when `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` is called the control of the program passes to `onCreateOptionsMenu` and since in that method I make a call to another method that should use something that should have been instantiated in `onCreateView`, the app crashes.

My solution was to put `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` at the end of the `onCreateView` thus making all instantiations be done correctly.

**One thing intriguing though. Why it worked on some devices and on others don't.**